# Review on polynomial quotient rings: $F[x]/(x^{4}-2x^{2}+1)$ & $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I have searched problems about quotient rings on our site. I think I now have a certain understanding about problem like

> (1) Find all ideals of $F[x]/(x^{4}-2x^{2}+1)$ when $F=\Bbb C, \Bbb R.$
>
> (2) Find all prime ideals which are not maximal of $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$.

I will show my work here and hopefully get your feedback.

For (1), I found related and helpful answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/831169/find-all-ideals-of-mathbb-rx-langle-x2-3x2-rangle?lq=1) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893142/the-number-of-ideals-in-the-quotient-ring-mathbb-rx-langle-x2-3x2-rangle?lq=1). I therefore can say
there are $9$ ideals of $F[x]/(x^{4}-2x^{2}+1)$ which are $I/(x^{4}-2x^{2}+1)$ where
$I=((x-1)^i(x+1)^j), i,j \in \{0,1,2\}$. The key here is that $F[x]$ is PID.

For (2), prime ideals of $\Bbb C[x,y]/(xy)$ are precisely prime ideals of  $\Bbb C[x,y]$ that
contain $(xy)$. We want to find the prime ideals that are not maximal.
[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56916/what-do-prime-ideals-in-kx-y-look-like) tells me these ideals are principal ideals $(f(x,y))$ where $f$ is irreducible.
In particular, $xy \in (f)$ we must have either $f=x$ or $f=y$ (excluded $f=1$).
As a consequence, ideals that we wanted to find are $(x)+(xy)$ and $(y)+(xy)$.
These are indeed prime by [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116917/why-does-kx-y-xy-have-two-minimal-primes).

Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: I've read your post and don't have nothing to say. (Eventually I can ask why consider *two* particular fields in the first question as long as the decomposition of that polynomial holds over any field, and add to the second the remark that non-maximal primes of that ring are in fact the minimal ones.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For the first question, I was wondering can we identify that ring to any well-known ring? For the second question, is it true that the only maximal prime of that ring is $(x,y)+(xy)$? If possible, please make yours as an answer. I truly want to make this post answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions from the comments.

1. We have $$F[X]/((X-1)^2(X+1)^2)\simeq F[X]/((X-1)^2)\times F[X]/((X+1)^2)$$ by [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings). Moreover,  the last one is isomorphic to $F[X]/(X^2)\times F[X]/(X^2)$.
2. There are many more maximal ideals containing $XY$ than $(X,Y)$. Notice that $(XY)\subset (X)\subset (X,f(Y))$ with $f\in K[Y]$ irreducible, and also $(XY)\subset (Y)\subset (Y,f(X))$ with $f\in K[X]$ irreducible. (In fact, these are all maximal ideals containing $XY$.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that the field is $K=\mathbb C$ in the second question. Then the maximal ideals containing $XY$ are $(X,Y-a)$ and $(X-a,Y)$, $a\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: It's alright. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.